# Perl - Finding missing numbers in an incremental list of values

Tags: perl

I need to find a way to find either none, one or more than one missing value in large sequences (200,000 plus)

The values are extracted from a document and placed into a text file. 
Because of the extraction, there would be blank spaces in between the values, so something like this could be used: `$str =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g`

The extraction looks something like this (seperated by 2, 3 or 4 blank spaces):

```
120000  120001    120003  120004  120005
```

Is there an easy way to extract these values directly from the text file and find any missing values using Perl?

Thank you!

Comment: is the source sequence guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: is there a inline or separate line may be also available

Comment: Yes, the sequence is always sorted, unless a number is of course missing :)

Comment: I can extract the data, so that each number goes on a new line also.

Comment: "I can extract the data, so that each number goes on a new line also.". You should update your question with this information...

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an easy way to extract these values directly from the text file

The simplest way would be to do this. It removes all whitespace as well as extracting the numbers

```
my @numbers = do{
    open my $fh, '<', 'document.txt' or die $!;
    local $/;
    <$fh> =~ /\d+/g;
};
```

---

> and find any missing values

Some people seem to think that an answer which helps only partially is completely useless. Here is the rest

I would use a module like `Number::Range`, like this

It passes the `@numbers` array straight into the constructor, and then uses the `rangeList` method to obtain the start and end pairs of all contiguous subsequences. The range of values that covers all of these is from the start of the first sequence to the end of the last one. This is constructed as a new array `$all`, and the original range deleted from it. That leaves just the gaps in the original range

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Number::Range;

my @numbers = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'document.txt' or die $!;
    local $/;
    <$fh> =~ /\d+/g;
};

my $range = Number::Range->new(@numbers);

my @sections = $range->rangeList;
my $all = Number::Range->new("$sections[0][0]..$sections[-1][-1]");
$all->delrange($range->range);

say scalar $all->range;
```

#### output

```
120002
```

Comment: So this would push all the values from the text file into numbers, correct? 
Then the next step would be to find the missing values from there.

Comment: @Markpw: Yes. Exactly

Comment: @simbabque: I answered part of the question. It seemed to be a particular issue for the OP given his machinations with `s/^\s+|\s+$//g`. It's strange to receive downvotes for not answering absolutely everything asked!

Comment: That's why I commented, but didn't vote.

Comment: @simbabque: I didn't imagine you had. You are smarter than that.

Comment: @Borodin: Thank you it works alright, the only issue I got now is when I reach a certain amount of numbers it simply returns first and last value.

When I test it with small arrays it works fine, but working with thousands of items..How would I go about optimising to data that size?

Comment: @Markpw: Can you put your data on line and post a link to it? This should work fine with any amount of data. Also, have you seen the solution in the duplicate question?

Comment: @Borodin: Sure thank you. https://github.com/Marpw/missingNumbers

The test input runs through fine - no missing values. <- I tested this with missing a few numbers and it works great.

With test_2 I changed the very last value to something a lot higher so the output should show the numbers between the second to last and last item missing. 

With test_3 I found that up to 1000, it runs through fine. Anything over it  just outputs the range instead.

Comment: Is there a limit maybe in the Number::Range module?

Answer (score 2):

If you have only integer numbers, you can just iterate the whole thing and keep the most recent number around, then check if the current number is one more. I left out the parsing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @missing;
my $last;
while ( my $current = <DATA> ) {
    $last ||= $current - 1; # start out with one less than the first

    push @missing, $current unless $last + 1 == $current;
    $last = $current;
}

p @missing;
__DATA__
120000
120001
120003
120004
120005
```

You need to initialize `$last` inside of the loop and set it to one less than the first number, or you will always have the first one included.

`@missing` will contain `120003`.

Comment: Might want to update the answer that also shows how to extract the numbers if they are all on the same line per the OP, just to cover all bases.

Comment: @stevieb [Borodin already did that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41265014/1331451), and [the OP knows how to get it into the format I used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264874/perl-finding-missing-numbers-in-an-incremental-list-of-values/41265014?noredirect=1#comment69730718_41264874).

Comment: `$last ||= $current - 1;` `||` means?

Comment: @ssr `||=` combines the [_logical or_](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Or) (which is `||`) and the assignment operator `=`. If the value on the left is true, nothing happens. If it's false, the value on the right is assigned to the value on the left. So this basically reads _if `$last` is not set, set it to `$current` minus one_. You could also express it as `$last = $current - 1 unless $last`.